# Regex Match Word with special character

Tags: java, regex

I would like to look for any word in a file containing different informations like date and percentage and some strings.

Input:

```
21-02-2015 wordA 22 wordB wordC
```

Result:

```
wordA wordB wordC
```

Please help me for I am new to regex.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you just have us give you the solution you will stay new to the subject forever

Comment: What's the rule here? Find words that begin with `word`? Find the second, fourth and fifth word? Find words not containing digits (which seems almost the opposite to the title)? Find words consisting of five characters? Also; are you using Java or Apple's library? Surely not both. And what has this got to do with lookarounds?

Comment: Biffen : Actually it is finding every string there are that make a word (eg : Hello or Name etc) I am using Java and my probleme is that I cannot seems to catch every word in my input with special character

Comment: @MedBEN Then you might want to change the title of the question. And please clean up the tags. Anyway, in what way is `22` not a word?

Comment: will do about the title but 22 is a digits and I dont want it in my result

Comment: @MedBEN So is that the rule, then? You want to match all words that don't contain digits?

Comment: yes  but words that I am working with contains some special character.

Comment: @MedBEN Which of the characters in `21-02-2015 wordA 22 wordB wordC` would you say are special? And I'm still curious about the tags; are you really parsing a regular language using `NSRegularExpression` in Java?

Comment: Biffen this is the regex "([a-zA-Z]+)" i am using to fetch the words in my input but it s not abel to find all the word (e.g : Førtids  )

Comment: @MedBEN How about split by spaces and then match each element against `[^\d]+`?

Comment: Actually  I tried this one and works (([a-zA-Z]+)(\W)?([a-zA-Z]+))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Java's regex implementation supports [character class intersection](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html), for which this is a textbook usecase.

`[\w&&[^\d]]` will thus match a word character but not a digit. Together with [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) it should match ‘special characters’.

Thus this code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class test {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    String  input   = "21-02-2015 wordA 22 wordB wordC Førtids";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[\\w&&[^\\d]]+",
                                      Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)
                      .matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find() ) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group() );
    }
  }

}
```

Produces:

```
wordA
wordB
wordC
Førtids
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex that could retrieve any string including special character answer found it :

```
 (([a-zA-Z]+)(\W)?([a-zA-Z]+))
```

- `([a-zA-Z]+)` Look for character  in **Aa-zZ**
- `(\W)` look for the special character
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` if the special character is in the middle you look for the rest of the word

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one ‘special’ character in one word. And why are you using so many capturing groups?

Comment: As I said I am new to regex and I am open to any suggestion